# HTML / AJAX / PHP FORM PROCESS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Hello my first post here.

I'm having troubles with some coding.  To start explaining I'll have an html form that has got 5 checkboxes and I need to pass variables via post method. The trouble than I'm having is that no matter if checkbox is checked or not, it sends the same content via post to php.

Ill have 3 archives.

```
1st HTML FORM
2nd .JS
3rd .PHP
```

On 1st archive (HTML) 
Checkboxes are set as:

```
input type="checkbox" class="form-control" id="cat_a" name="cat_a" value="A"<br>
input type="checkbox" class="form-control" id="cat_b" name="cat_a" value="B"<br>
input type="checkbox" class="form-control" id="cat_c" name="cat_a" value="C"<br>
input type="checkbox" class="form-control" id="cat_d" name="cat_a" value="D"<br>
input type="checkbox" class="form-control" id="cat_e" name="cat_a" value="E"<br>
```

On my second archive .JS
I'll define it as:

```
var cat_a = $("input#cat_a").val();<br>
var cat_b = $("input#cat_b").val();<br>
var cat_c = $("input#cat_c").val();<br>
var cat_d = $("input#cat_d").val();<br>
var cat_e = $("input#cat_e").val();<br>
```

and then

```
      $.ajax({
            url: "././mail/contact_me.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                cat_a: cat_a,
                cat_b: cat_b,
                cat_c: cat_c,
                cat_d: cat_d,
                cat_e: cat_e,
```

3rd archive .php

```
$cat_a = $_POST['cat_a'];<br>
$cat_b = $_POST['cat_b'];<br>
$cat_c = $_POST['cat_c'];<br>
$cat_d = $_POST['cat_d'];<br>
$cat_e = $_POST['cat_e'];<br>
```

and send it

```
$email_body = "Categoria:\n$cat_a\n$cat_b\n$cat_c\n$cat_d\n$cat_e\nConsulta:\n$message";
```

The trouble I'm having is that no matter if its checked or not send the values, maybe I'm initializing the values or something. Really I'm new at programming and cannot see what's my error...

I want as a final result to recibe by email if user checks for example option A,B and C to recibe via email  (do not care if its crude as ABC) but right now I'm getting ABCDE no matter if checkboxes are clicked or not!.

thanks in advance!.
Hope someone helps me!.

Comment: Code formatting exists for a reason. Please use it for your code.

Comment: You're obtaining the value of each checkbox, what you want to do is obtain whether or not the check box is selected IE. $("input#cat_e").is(:checked); which will return a true or false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `.prop('checked') === true` or as the other gentleman pointed out, you can use `.is(':checked')` as well.

> Using ***.prop()***

```
var cat_a = $("#cat_a").prop('checked') === true ? 'A' : '';
```

> Using ***.is()***

```
var cat_a = $("#cat_a").is(':checked') ? 'A' : '';
```

> OR if you **don't** like ***ternary*** operators

```
if ($("#cat_a").prop('checked') === true) {
   var cat_a = 'A';
} else {
   var cat_a = '';
}
```

Comment: Ternary operators are like waffles.  Everybody likes them.

Comment: You would think so right?   I get so many people giving me a hard time for using ternary.

Comment: EXCELENT! Notorious Pet0

Comment: @Fernandojp Glad I could help!  Please click the little checkmark to the left of my answer to indicate that it is correct.  Thanks! :)